# IntelliJ & Global Config Files

Tags: intellij-idea

I've been searching for a solution but I can't find one.

I have a global configuration directory in my IntelliJ workspace. I also have several dozen modules. I would like each module to automatically include the global config directory in its path when I run or test a class.

Is there anyway to do this within IntelliJ? I don't think I should need to edit the configuration for each "Run/Debug" config to include the directory.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to set it in the **Defaults** for the type of **Run or Debug Configuration** that you are using.

For example, if I always want a **Java Application** to have the **VM Option** `-XPutYourThingyHere`, then I could go to **Edit Configurations**, **Defaults**, **Application**, and put `-XPutYourThingyHere` in the **VM Options** box. Then all new Applications that I run will have that option.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Kirby. But there is no setting for classpath here unless I am mistaken. I need/want to add the global config dir to the classpath. I tried adding -cp MyDir to the VM options and then adding CLASSPATH to environment variables but I suspect both are being overwritten when the program starts.

Comment: Ah. I misunderstood. I've been using Maven with Intellij for so long that I have forgotten how to do what you are asking. There is a way to declare a common directory environment variable and have it respected by Intellij's external library linking, but it escapes me at the moment